# App clash while accessing parent acitvity from oncreate of child acivity

Tags: android, android-activity

App crashes while accessing parent activity from oncreate of child activity. Tried code as follows

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SDCard.SDCardInterface {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ((SDCard)getParent()).setSDCardInterface(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void Show(String show){
    Toast.makeText(this, "TestAcivity OK "+show, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

I called child activity from mainactivity as follows

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, TestActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Error Log as follows

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mtxlabs.cameraviewer, PID: 9566
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mtxlabs.cameraviewer/com.mtxlabs.cameraviewer.sdcard.TestActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.mtxlabs.cameraviewer.sdcard.TestActivity.onCreate(TestActivity.java:16)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: getparent() Return the parent activity if this view is an embedded child.

Comment: @jagapathi i called child activity via Intent

Comment: You can't interact with parent activity like this, if you want pass data to parent you need to start activity via `startActivityForResult`

Comment: @ShayanPourvatan I want to sent data to child activity on frequent intervals.  Is it possible /

Comment: why you need this as your child activity not visible?

Comment: @ShayanPourvatan NOT VISIBLE ?

Comment: Use 2 fragments in 1 Activity instead.

Comment: I mean parent activity, if you need pass frequently you can use fragment instead of activity

Comment: better you run a service for that @Riskhan to receive data frequently

Comment: @jagapathi I want to show an image which received from main activity

Answer (score 0):

The reason is in this line

```
((SDCard)getParent()).setSDCardInterface(this);
```

You called `getParent()` which will return `Activity`. However you are casting it to `SDCard` => it will throw NullPointerException.

Comment: Yes my main activity and TestActivity are extends AppCompactActivity

Comment: I have edited my answer. What you are doing incorrectly is that you are casting `getParent()` to `SDCard`.

Comment: SDCard is parent activity of TestActivity

Comment: Have you declared android:parentActivityName="com.yourpackage.SDCard" under TestActivity in Manifest?